# Tweepy - Print All Fields from All User Objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

Been searching for a hour, can't find how to print out the fields of a user object in Tweepy:

```
 userobjects = tweepy.API(auth).search_users('china', 20, 1)
 print userobjects
```

Prints the objects:

```
<tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e69e710>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e69e750>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469b50>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469bd0>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469cd0>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469d50>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469e10>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469e90>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469f10>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e469f90>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476090>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476150>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476210>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476290>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476310>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e4763d0>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476450>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e4764d0>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e4765d0>, <tweepy.models.User object at 0x10e476690>
```

How do I print [the fields inside of the objects](http://tkang.blogspot.com/2011/01/tweepytwitter-api-user-object-structure.html)?

Comment: have you ever tried for example userobjects[0].me().name ?

Comment: userobjects[0].name works. no need for .me() This is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 print userobjects[0].name
```

prints the first object's username in the list. Just iterate for all objects in list and for whatever other fields you need inside that object.